# API name change from DEV to FULL

Tags: api, administration, custom-field, change-set, admin

I have a field with same label name and API name in DEV and FULL. I would like to rename the API name in DEV and move it to FULL using change set. Would it rename the API name in full or would it create a new field with the different API name. Would it create a duplicate?

Comment: The answer is going to be the same for pretty much everything: fields, objects, profiles, permission sets, record types, Visualforce pages, components, Apex classes, triggers, page layouts, buttons, links, labels, profiles... pretty much anything you can put in to a change set. If the \<insert whatever here\> came by a change set or was created because of a new sandbox or refresh, the developer name will magically change for you (assuming it doesn't break anything), otherwise it will be created as a duplicate.

Comment: It created a duplicate in FULL when I moved the same field label name with a different field name from DEV. I guess the reason might be that API name was used in some of the workflow rules.

Comment: Again, it depends on how the field was originally created. Change sets generally "DWIM" (Do What I Mean) as long as your orgs are primarily managed by change sets, they work as you expect. Once you start creating fields in both orgs without change sets, then you have to rely on API names to match up. Odds are, the field in question wasn't in sync and so a duplicate was created.

Comment: Do we create a change set just to update the field name? Is it necessary?

Comment: @sfdcfox if we created a field in a org using change set, then will it rename the field api name if you send another change set with different api name?

Comment: If you have a field label name same in different org, say DEV and FULL. but the api names are different. Now if you move the field name from DEV to FULL using change set, it will create a duplicate field with the API name that was in DEV.